# Python - How to identify a string containing a sequence of repeated letters

Tags: python

For instance, if I have a file containing a large number of lines, with each line having a string like this:

TTCCGACTGACTTACGAAAAAA

I would like to identify the lines with strings that have a sequence of a letter 'A'. For example, above string has 'A' repeated six times at the end. I would like to identify those strings with 'A' repeated more than 3 times. Is there a way to do this in python?

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: You can write a logic for it, even if there is no pre-defined library function.

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: A repeated more than three times anywhere or only at last???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Regular Expression` is best to use here:

A 3 or more anywhere:

```
>>> s="TTCCGACTGACTTACGAAAAAA"
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('A{3,}',s)
>>> if m:
...     print"A is more than 3 times"
... 
A is more than 3 times
```

to check at end:

```
>>> m = re.search('A{3,}$',s)
>>> if m:
...     print"A is more than 3 times at end"
... 
A is more than 3 times at end
```

A{3,} will match AAA or AAAA or more . but ti will not match A, AA
I have shown for 3 or more, if your want more than 3 use `A{4,}`
Learn about Regular Expression Here:[Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Thanks for this! I have put off learning RE, but I should do that now.

Comment: Yes its very powerfull. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to read your file line by line (the 1st two lines in my code are practically an idiom) and check if the string 'AAAA' (more than three consecutive A's) is contained in the current line.

If the current line contains 'AAAA' then you have to process it...

```
with open('your_data_file') as f:
     for line in f:
         if 'AAAA' in line:
            process(line)

...
```

Slightly more compact and more obscure

```
with open('your_data_file') as f:
     for line in (l in f if 'AAAA' in l):
         process(line)
```

This particular construct is called a [generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Note that in the second example you loop ONLY on the matching lines and this may be what you want to do, or not... if you want to do something for all lines and something special for the matching ones, then go with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `if 'A'*3 in line`. so that 'A'*3 = `AAA` is in line by `if` clause.

```
with open(somefile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'A'*3 in line:
            do something.
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use this function on every line of your file.

```
def has_s_a_sequence_of_three_as_in_it(s):
    for i in range(0,len(s)-3 ):
        if s[i:i+4] == 'AAAA':
            return True
    return False

print(has_s_a_sequence_of_three_as_in_it('dasdasdasdasAAAA')) # True
print(has_s_a_sequence_of_three_as_in_it('dAAAasAdasdAAAasdasAA')) # False
print(has_s_a_sequence_of_three_as_in_it('dasdAAAAAAAasdasdas')) # True
```

Comment: Why would you manually check each substring when you can check `if 'AAAA' in s` in one line?

Comment: Sometimes I do not think pythonic enough :D